# Is there any method to create an audio visualizer as seen in video below

Tags: audio

So I've been looking for a certain effect to add to videos for my channel, and in doing so I can safely say that the internet is filled with useless and endless templates for simple audio visualizations or ungodly expensive suites that can't do what I actually want to do. (or at least similar)

There are three videos below, I believe them to have been rendered in After Effects.

this one is why I know it to be After Effects,

The uploader says to have been using javascript math expressions, alas I can not find anything where I could learn how to do anything close to that. Particles or no particles.  I'm more looking at trying to find something I can learn from rather than "can someone do this."  If there is any free resources out there I could possibly use?

The channel I linked has long been abandoned.

Edit: I can't even add the tags to this post of "Particles" or "Visualizer"

Comment: If you're on a mac, you should look into "Quartz Composer".  It's free from Apple if you register as a developer.  It's what they build all of their screensavers with, and it's waaay easier to learn than javascript.  I believe there's still also a large-ish support community, although I haven't been involved since OSX Leopard.

Answer (score 1):

Audio Spectrum effect that comes with After Effects. Just apply the effect to a solid layer and there will be a dropdown of the layers in the current composition, select the audio layer.